# How to add any dll from bin to NuGet Library

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I have a console application named CLI and I have configured the csproj for NuGet pacakage library like following:

```
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
<RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
      https://nuget.---.com/v3/index.json;
</RestoreAdditionalProjectSources>
<RootNamespace>CLI</RootNamespace>

<!-- Nuget settings --> 
<Title>CLI</Title>
<PackageVersion>1.0.0</PackageVersion>
<Copyright>Copyright © 2022 XXXXXXXXXXX</Copyright>
<Authors>Root</Authors>
<Description>A CLI based client to access the Web APIs.</Description>
<Company>XXXXXXXXXXX</Company>
<Version>5</Version>
<IsPackable>true</IsPackable>

<ItemGroup>
    <None Include=".\Images\icon.png">
        <Pack>True</Pack>
        <PackagePath>\</PackagePath>
    </None>
    <Content Include="bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\*.dll">
        <Pack>true</Pack>
        <PackagePath>lib\net6.0</PackagePath>
    </Content>
</ItemGroup>
```

It creates a Nuget Library, but when I add it as NuGet reference to a project and tried to run the cli.dll file using command line, it throws the following error:

```
A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'D:\Projects\TestCLINuget\TestCLINuget\bin\Debug\net6.0\'.
```

I dont know how to add hostpolicy.dll file within NuGet package so that when the NuGet library is added to a test project and we build that test project, then I should get the cli.dll file running if I write

```
dotnet cli.dll
```

or am I missing something else?